# Increment query string parameters using jquery function on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I'm making a next page system in which you click on 'next' and it takes you to the next set of elements.

This is the button in php:

```
    <input id="nextbtn" type="button" value="Next"></input>
```

This is the jquery function:

```
$('#nextbtn').click(function(){

});
```

The URL is:  `www.domain.com?var1=0&var2=20`

I want to increment `var1` and `var2` by 20 everytime the 'next' button is clicked.
Please tell me the code I should write in the jquery function so that this works.

Comment: jQuery is not needed for that. You can retrieve the values with PHP ($_GET array) and calculate the next URL based on that.

Comment: Considering you mentioned that you're using PHP, you won't even need to do this calculation in JavaScript at all, but rather in PHP.

Comment: You are right but the url will change on button click, the page will refresh and the variables `$var1 = $_GET['var1']` will get the new values. I need to know how to change the query string on button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get query string current value:

```
function getQueryStringParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Now call this function in your next button click and add increment value:

```
var var1 = parseInt(getQueryStringParameterByName('var1'),10)+20;
var var2 = parseInt(getQueryStringParameterByName('var2'),10)+20;
```

and set it to url and redirect.

Comment: ok, the variable var1 and var2 are to be placed in the click function.
Since my page also consists of php, where do I place the function getQueryStringParameterByName(name)?

Comment: It worked.
To set the variables in the url, I used:
     `var hrf="www.domain.com/x.php?var1=" + var1 + "&var2=" +var2;             document.getElementById("a_link1").href=hrf;`

Comment: what if domain can be both http and https